# How can this proposition be proved?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Look at this example (Example 1):
[image]

[image]
[This picture is from the book ''Advanced Engineering Mathematics'' by ''Erwin Kreyszig'']

This example is about linear fractional transformations, that is ,transformations in the form
$$(1){\rm{               }}w = {{az + b} \over {cz + d}}$$
The example says: ''since $z = i$ gives $w = 0$ and $w = 0$ is inside the unit circle So we infer inductively that the upper half plane maps onto the interior of that circle and the lower half plane onto the exterior''(This section is highlighted in red)

Now, I want to know how to prove this proposition for all points

Answer (score 2):

A linear fractional transformation $w : \overline{\mathbb{C}} \to \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ can be proven to map extended lines and circles onto extended lines and circles (an extended line is the union of a line and $\infty$). See proposition 20.4 on page 265 of [this complex analysis book](https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/complex.pdf) for a proof.

His computation showed that $w$ maps the $x$-axis onto the unit circle. Since $w$ is a homeomorphism, a connectedness argument shows that either $w$ maps the upper half plane onto the unit disk or $w$ maps the upper half plane onto $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$. You only need to compute $w(z)$ for one point $z$ in the upper half plane to determine which case is true.

Answer (score 1):

The following equality holds: $$\omega(z)=\frac{z-i}{-iz+1}=i\frac{z-i}{z+i}=i\frac{(z-i)^2}{|z+i|^2}$$

Now we observe that for $z=a+ib$ with $a,b$ reals and $b$ positive it holds that $|z-i|\lt |z+i|$ so we can conclude that $|\omega(z)|\lt 1$ if $z$ belongs to the upper complex plane, and this tell us that the image of upper plane is contained in the ball of radius 1 and centered in the origin....

Can you infer what happens to $|\omega(z)|$ when $z$ belongs to the lower complex plane
?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have examined your answer and I must say that I myself came to this conclusion in a similar way to yours. My method is as follows: If we put x + i y instead of z then ${{z - i} \over { - iz + 1}} = {{x + iy - i} \over { - i(x + iy) + 1}} = {{x + (y - 1)i} \over {y + 1 - ix}}$ Whose magnitude is equal to ${{\sqrt {{x^2} + {{(y - 1)}^2}} } \over {\sqrt {{x^2} + {{(y + 1)}^2}} }} = {{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2} - 2y + 1} } \over {\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2} + 2y + 1} }}$

Comment: When y is positive, its numerator is smaller than its denominator, hence the size of w is  smaller than one and w is inside the unit circle, but if y is negative, the numerator is larger and w is outside the unit circle. Nevertheless, I think there may be a more elegant way to prove this statement. If we can prove that for every y the point z = x + i y is mapped onto a circle on the plane w which is tangent to the line v = 1 from above in the point $(0,i)$ and its radius increases with increasing y and when y = 1 coincides with the unit circle, then we have proved this statement in a more

Comment: elegant way. I think it is possible but I don't know how to do it

Comment: For the most elegant answer, and probably the one implicitly used by kreyzig, give a look at @Mason 's answer